What should I do with a package that is delivered to my address but the name is wrong?
It seems that the package is for the person who lived in my apartment previously. I have no way of contacting them. What should I do with the package?

Shipping/postal services should have processes to refuse delivery/return to sender in such situation, inquire with them.

Where the "return to sender" might be nominal and the item is destroyed. But that's not for you to worry about.

This question is similar to: Is it illegal to throw away the previous tenant's mail?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In the case of the United States Postal Service, mark the package:

Return to sender, addressee unknown

and put it with other outgoing mail.

Works with UK (Royal Mail) also, although I think that if it has obviously been opened (and maybe re-sealed) the original sender can be surcharged as if it was an unstamped item addressed to them.

Another common phrasing is “no longer at this address” (maybe more appropriate here than “unknown”).

With USPS (and similar) it is easy to "Return to Sender" because they stop at every address nearly every day. With UPS, FedEx, etc. it can be a bit more complicated, particularly if you don't happen to live or work near a drop box or shipping location for a particular delivery service.

No such number, no such zone.

For those too young to get the reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCa2lpIR7f4

FWIW, and as per the USPS FAQ they say "Write Not at this address on the mailpiece

I'm not sure that this is entirely a legal question, but I would actually recommend making an effort to return the package to the person who ordered it before giving it to the Post Office. They may well not have access to many more resources than anyone else to locate the intended recipient, and whether they actually will employ those resources will depend on numerous factors beyond the control of the unintended recipient.

It is often much easier than it seems to return lost or misdirected items. In just the last few years, I have been able to track down the intended recipients or owners of a pair of shoes shipped to a previous tenant of my apartment, an ID left by someone who lived thousands of miles away, and even, with substantial difficulty, a damaged smartphone with a broken screen. In the case of this question, even though the poster says that they do not have any way to contact the recipient, it is very likely that the owner or management company of the apartment still has their contact information.
